# Designing junit test cases - predefined steps for each test case

Tags: java, junit

I am interested in getting ideas on how can I design my junit test cases so that they are more readable and maintainable. Here is the problem - In all my junit test cases I have some predefined steps to be executed like below

```
public class MyTestClass {

private Service myService;

@Test
public void testCase1() {
    mockObjectX("A");
    mockObjectY(1);
    mockObjectZ("M", 1);

    myService.validate("value1", "value2");

}

@Test
public void testCase2() {
    mockObjectX("Q");
    mockObjectY(5);
    mockObjectZ("Z", 10);

    myService.validate("value3", "value4");

}


private void mockObjectZ(String value1, int value2) {
    //mock object Z
}

private void mockObjectY(Integer value) {
    //mock object Y
}

private void mockObjectX(String value) {
    //mock object X
}
}
```

The issue is if I were to add a new test case I need make sure that the new test case calls mockObjectX(), mockObjectY(), mockObjectZ(). Is there a better way (a more maintainable way) of designing my test cases such that adding new testcases becomes simpler?

I think that @Before cannot be used since the mock* methods accept parameters.

One way I could think of is having a class containing methods for each parameter value required to mock object X, Y and Z

```
public class MyTestClass {

private Service myService;

@Test
public void testCase1() {
    mockObjects(new TestCase1());
    myService.validate("value1", "value2");

}

@Test
public void testCase2() {
    mockObjects(new TestCase2());
    myService.validate("value3", "value4");

}

private void mockObjects(ServiceObjectMocker serviceObjectMocker) {
    //mock object x, y and z by calling respective methods from serviceObjectMocker   
}  

private class ServiceObjectMocker {

    protected Object[] getValuesForObjectZ() {
        //pass default values
        return new Object[] {};     
    }

    protected Integer getValuesForObjectY() {
        //pass default values
        return 1;
    }

    protected String getValuesForObjectX() {
        //pass default values
        return "A";
    }

}

private class TestCase1 extends ServiceObjectMocker {
    @Override
    protected String getValuesForObjectX() {
        return "B";    
    }  
}

private class TestCase2 extends ServiceObjectMocker {
    @Override
    protected String getValuesForObjectX() {
        //pass different values
        return "Q";
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer getValuesForObjectY() {
        //pass default values
        return 10;
    }

}
}
```

This reduces the no. of method calls each test case needs to make. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really area doing the same thing each time, it's just the data that varies, then look at [@Parameterized](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html).

You could then have something like (untested and uncompiled):

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MyTestClass {
  @Parameters
  public static List<Object[]> data() {
      return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
          { "A", 1, "M", 1, "value1", "value2" },
          { "Q", 5, "Z", 10, "value3", "value4" },
      });
  }

  private String xValue;
  private int yValue;
  private String zValueString;
  private int zValueInt;
  private String expected1;
  private String expected2;

  public MyTestClass(String xValue, int yValue, String zValueString, int zValueInt, String expected1, String expected2) {
    this.xValue = xValue;
    this.yValue = yValue;
    this.zValueString = zValueString;
    this.zValueInt = zValueInt;
    this.expected1 = expected1;
    this.expected2 = expected2;
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    mockObjectX(xValue);
    mockObjectY(yValue);
    mockObjectZ(zValueString, zValueInt);

    myService.validate(expected1, expected2);
  }
}
```

You are then only defining your test once.

Comment: I still have to call the three methods - mockObjectX, mockObjectY and mockObjectZ and that's what I wanted to reduce down to make the test cases more maintainable.

Comment: You said: "The issue is if I were to add a new test case I need make sure that the new test case calls mockObjectX(), mockObjectY(), mockObjectZ(). Is there a better way (a more maintainable way) of designing my test cases such that adding new testcases becomes simpler?". To add a new test case to the Parameterized, you need to add a line to the list returned by data(). Is this not what you were looking for?

Comment: I got your point. I tried using @Parmeterized with ServiceObjectMocker and it works out well. Thanks!